# Ajax output w/css styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I am trying to understand some code given to me, it uses an autocomplete script to pull data from a SQL database, and output it when called from a form(user enters a few letters).  I want to modify the css that relates to the script, but cannot seem to find where its located?  Here is the script :

```
//autocomplete script
$(document).on('focus','.autocomplete_txt',function(){
    type = $(this).data('type');

    if(type =='productCode' )autoTypeNo=0;
    if(type =='productName' )autoTypeNo=1;  

    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {  
             var array = $.map(prices, function (item) {
                 var code = item.split("|");
                 return {
                     label: code[autoTypeNo],
                     value: code[autoTypeNo],
                     data : item
                 }
             });
             //call the filter here
             response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(array, request.term));
        },
        autoFocus: true,            
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            var names = ui.item.data.split("|");                        
            id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
            id = id_arr.split("_");
            element_id = id[id.length-1];
            $('#itemNo_'+element_id).val(names[0]);
            $('#itemName_'+element_id).val(names[1]);
            $('#quantity_'+element_id).val(1);
            $('#price_'+element_id).val(names[2]);
            $('#total_'+element_id).val( 1*names[2] );
            calculateTotal();
        }               
    });
});
```

Sample of code using script :

```
<tr id="tr_<?php echo $key+1?>">
    <td> <input class="case" type="checkbox"/> </td>
    <td class="prod_c">
        <input value="<?php echo isset($item['product_id']) ? $item['product_id']: ''; ?>" type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data[InvoiceDetail][<?php echo $key;?>][product_id]" id="itemNo_<?php echo $key+1?>" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">
        <span class="add_icon hide" id="add_icon_<?php echo $key+1?>"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
    </td>
```

I tried to find via the web developer inspector in firefox, but it will not let me highlight the generated data.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like they may have been using bootstrap (based on the `form-control` class on the form element, it's a shot in the dark). There is probably some custom stylesheet somewhere.

Comment: It is bootstrap, but what is the control for the interior of a form text box when autocomplete script runs?

Comment: Well, judging by the JavaScript code I'd say they are using jQuery UI autocomplete for Bootstrap. You should search for that if you want to manipulate the style. Here is an example of what I found via google search: https://gist.github.com/daz/2168334

Comment: mason, your link solved my question, if you post I will select as answer and explain why

Comment: I'm glad that helped. I posted as an answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they are using Bootstrap and jQuery UI Autocomplete. Here is an example of a modified styled for that:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  float: left;
  display: none;
  min-width: 160px;
  _width: 160px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  *border-right-width: 2px;
  *border-bottom-width: 2px;

  .ui-menu-item > a.ui-corner-all {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 15px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #555555;
    white-space: nowrap;

    &.ui-state-hover, &.ui-state-active {
      color: #ffffff;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: #0088cc;
      border-radius: 0px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
      -moz-border-radius: 0px;
      background-image: none;
    }
  }
}
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/daz/2168334

Comment: I ended up being able to find the code by right-clicking the element within firefox, and selecting "Inspect Element". I was able to narrow down the css file(there are quite a few) due to your posting.

Answer (score 0):

you could use jquery $(this).css to set some styling or you could use chrome developer tools to pinpoint the element you are targeting.

This snippet will change the color of the text to red on a focus event

```
$(document).on('focus','.autocomplete_txt',function(){
  $(this).css("color", "red" )
}
```

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/basics?hl=en

http://api.jquery.com/css/